# Black Border Around gnome-system-monitor in X11 on Windows 10

Tags: xorg

I am new to elementary OS. I am using VcXsrv to open some apps in Windows 10 1909 remotely using X11 Forwarding in Putty with elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera.  Most everything works perfectly.  However, I have a problem exporting gnome-system-monitor.  It opens with an ~ 2cm black border around the application.

I have tried with and without *export "LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1"* and it displays the same behavior.  I only have this problem with elementary OS.  I can't replicate it using Ubuntu LTS 18.04.  I have attached an image to show the problem better.

I realize that gnome-system-monitor is not a native application for elementary OS, but I was unable to find another app that was native and provided the visual functionality of gnome-system-monitor.

Am I stuck with this border?  Is there a native elementary OS app that provides all the features of gnome-system-monitor?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Strangely, I see the same black border when viewing any Elementary apps in Xquartz on macOS, be it io.elementary.code or io.elementary.terminal